# On-chain size of Anchor programs

Tags: anchor, build-bpf

I noticed that a minimal Anchor Program, e.g. [this here](https://github.com/bernieblume/addMeta) takes up over 400kB of executable data on the blockchain. I checked another, a bit more elaborate program, and it's taking up 800kB.

Given all the extreme lengths that Solana is going to in order to be efficient af (as in: the fastest blockchain in the world), this amount of space seems rather large to me.

Is this all due to Anchor overhead? Some sort of common (library) code that every program will get?

As for the second, more elaborate (and closed source) program, there is some 1,000 lines of Rust code, which I doubt will take up another 400kB of space. That would be like ~400 bytes of BPF for each line of Rust...

Can someone explain where all this code is coming from, and how I could help avoid overhead?

Here's the toolchain versions I'm using:

```
bb@strelizia:app/nodestore % cargo-build-bpf --version
solana-cargo-build-bpf 1.10.25
bpf-tools v1.27
bb@strelizia:app/nodestore %
```

Btw, due to the size, it costs me > 4 SOL to deploy the minimal [addmeta](https://github.com/bernieblume/addMeta). That's the reason I didn't deploy it to Mainnet, which turned out to be a mistake since I later learned that `create_metadata_accounts_v3` hasn't been deployed to Mainnet yet... ☠️

When I deployed the NodeStore program (~ 1 kLoc of Rust, with Anchor) to Mainnet, it has cost me more than 8 SOL.

Binary sizes see [here for addMeta](https://explorer.solana.com/address/FtFDrN3avLVCFYnoHurG8NhbG8pXkuzLDxGG4egzyHT6?cluster=devnet), now even up to over 500kB and [here for NodeStore](https://explorer.solana.com/address/7mUHSw7tptiBZaMVMmWB9k53EYrjw3e5e61CAgut4XhM), now even up to 1.1MB.

Comment: Can you please add the toolchain version to your post? `cargo-build-bpf --version`

Comment: `cargo-build-bpf --version` gives me `solana-cargo-build-bpf 1.10.25`
 `bpf-tools v1.27`

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's some evidence that a bug was introduced sometime after `bpf-tools` v1.23.  The compiler team is still looking into it, so unfortunately the best advice I can offer is to try to downgrade

Comment: Hm OK... Do you know approximately how much space I would save? It's now live on Mainnet, I paid my 8 SOL so they are gone now, and it's a hassle to downgrade, redeploy on Mainnet, etc. Maybe I'll just wait until it's fixed in newer version. Do you have any reference/links to the evidence a bug was introduced with regards to the size of the .so file?

Comment: I don't recall off hand, but I believe it was on the order of 500k of excess padding between two ELF sections

Comment: is there a fix expected soon ? any way for us to track it ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that big part of deploy cost is account space allocation with [rent exemption](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#rent-exemption). So after you close program (`solana program close <program-address>`) you can return most of your paid fees.

If you don't plan to upgrade your program, you can set exact allocation size of account using `solana program deploy program.so --max-len <size-bytes>`. By default it is [twice in size](https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program#redeploy-a-program) and can't be changed after initial deployment

Another way to optimize your Anchor program size is to use `default = ["no-idl"]` in `Cargo.toml` if you don't plan to publish IDL

**Warning!** After you close program you can't re-upload it to the same address